# Characteristic function of real part of complex random variable

Tags: probability, complex-numbers, characteristic-functions

I have a complex-valued random variable $X$ and I know the formula for $E\left[e^{\phi X}\right]$, for any $\phi\in\mathbb{C}$. It also happens that $P[Im(X)=y]=P[Im(X)=-y]$, i.e the probability density of the imaginary part of $X$ is symmetric around zero.

Based on this information, is there a way to calculate  $E\left[e^{\phi Re(X)}\right]$?

Comment: No, that is not possible. BTW you description of  symmetric random variable applies only to discrete random variables.

Comment: OK, what would be the correct notation? The PDF is symmetric.